# using Jsoup my application has been stopped forcefully

Tags: android, jsoup

hi friends i m using this tutorial http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/android-xml-adventure-parsing-html-using-jsoup/ and after i implemented this code my application has been stopped   i dont know why plz suggest me thanks in advance

```
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at your.packag.namespace.JsopuexampleActivity.getBlogStats(JsopuexampleActivity.java:33)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at your.packag.namespace.JsopuexampleActivity.onCreate(JsopuexampleActivity.java:24)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-12 17:35:29.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is jar issue.

Do following.

create a folder in the "root" of the app heirarchy (alongside src, gen, etc) called "libs", and put jar file there. When you clean / build and re-launch the app, the error should go away.

Below is correct code.

```
package org.sample;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Hello extends Activity {

    final String BLOG_URL = "http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/";
    private String result;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // set layout view
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getBlogStats();

    }

    protected void getBlogStats() {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Please Wait!");
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                Document document;
                try {
                    document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
                    Elements nodeBlogStats = document
                            .select("div#blog-stats ul li");

                    if (nodeBlogStats.size() > 0) {
                        result = nodeBlogStats.get(0).text();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    result = "Error";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(result);
                    }
                });

            }
        }.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks vipul but still getting problem its  show error in text view means exception is there plz try to resolve it

Comment: JsopuexampleActivity.java:24 <--- you have error in this line.paste your source code here.

Comment: source code is in below tutorial http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/android-xml-adventure-parsing-html-using-jsoup/

Comment: hey vipul i caught the exception its "android.os.networkonmainthreadexception" so what can i do ????

Comment: You are running your application in post 3.0 android version.so you must use thread to call document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();

Comment: If this solution worked than Accept this as solution so it will  helpful for others who are facing similar issue.